# Is there any PowerScript compilers?

Tags: powerbuilder

I'm very new to PowerBuilder world.

I've got a bunch of pbl files that I'm looking through with PBL Peeper.

Is there any way I can compile these into pbds or dlls without using PowerBuilder ?

Ultimately, is there a way I can use notepad to write code in PowerScript and build an application without using PowerBuilder ? Just like how you would/could do in Java ?

(I'm coming from Java background)

Answer (score 2):

There are some third party tools (like PowerBatch http://sqlbatch.com/pbc/ and PowerGen https://ecrane.com/powergen-overview/) which can be used to do a compile of the .pbls but you still need a copy of PowerBuilder to use them.

You could write PowerScript in a text editor but you would have to 'copy/paste' it into the script editor in PowerBuilder to save the code to an object in a .pbl file.  This would be very time consuming and the potential for errors very high.